# Data execution plan ended with error on DB restore

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, database-restore

I was trying to execute a script on power Shell which had to backup a database on one Azure server and then restore it in another server (always Azure). The script is going wrong in 2 points:

1. When i execute the script against an existing DB, it does not drop (or kill) a database before restoring, even though there is the procedure that should do that.
2. When i execute the script against a new created DB, i get this error:

> powershell : Exception calling "ImportBacpac" with "2" argument(s):
>   "Data plan execution  At line:1 char:1
>   + powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass –File C:\Untitled1.ps1 –noexit
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Exception calli...plan execution :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   failed with message One or more errors occurred." At C:\Untitled1.ps1:48 char:5
>   +     $Services.ImportBacpac($Package, $restoreToDatabaseName)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DataException

The code that i am using is the following:

```
[string]$azureConnectionString = "Server=myserver.database.windows.net; User ID=myUser; Password=MyPWD; Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True; Connection Timeout=30;"
[string]$azureDatabaseName = "SourceDb"
[string]$bacpacFileDropLocation = "path where to create the bacpac file"
[string]$restoreToServer = 'secondserver'
[string]$restoreToDatabaseName="DestinationDb"
[string]$restoreToConnectionString = "Server=secondserver.database.windows.net,1433; User ID=User; Password=Pwd; Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True; Connection Timeout=30;"
[string]$SqlInstallationFolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
Write-Host "Backing up Azure database '$azureDatabaseName' and restoring to database '$restoreToDatabaseName'"

$Watch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.StopWatch
$Watch.Start()
$DacAssembly = "$SqlInstallationFolder\120\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$smo= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
Add-Type -Path $DacAssembly
Add-Type -Path $smo
$Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $azureConnectionString

if ($Services -eq $null)
{ 
    Write-Host "Failed to load Sql Server Dac Services"
    exit
}

$Services.ExportBacpac($bacpacFileDropLocation, $azureDatabaseName)

if (test-path($bacpacFileDropLocation))
{      
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
    $SMOserver = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') -argumentlist $restoreToServer
    Write-Host "$SMOserver.Databases[$restoreToDatabaseName]"
    Write-Host "$restoreToDatabaseName"
    if  ($SMOserver.Databases[$restoreToDatabaseName] -ne $null) 
    {  
       # $SMOserver.Databases[$restoreToDatabaseName].Drop()  
       $SMOserver.KillDatabase($restoreToDatabaseName)
   } 
    else {Write-Host "Database not dropped"
    }

    $Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $restoreToConnectionString
    Write-Host $Services
    if ($Services -eq $null)
    {
        exit
    }

    $Package =  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($bacpacFileDropLocation)
    $Services.ImportBacpac($Package, $restoreToDatabaseName)
    $Package.Dispose()
    $Watch.Stop();
    Write-Host "Azure backup and local restore completed in "$Watch.Elapsed.ToString()
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Back up has failed!"
}
```

Is logical that when i execute the script on a new Db, the message "Database not dropped" shows up, but it also shows up when I execute it against an existing Db. Maybe is there something wrong in y script? I am a newbie and so is harder for me to debug such code

Comment: Try collecting the errors that occurred in the script. They can vary heavily and still result in "One or more errors occurred" as a script result.

Comment: @Vesper as I have already explained, since I have no experience in scripting, I don't have any idea how to debug the code. By putting some Write-Host where I thought there were points of failure, i understood that the line: $SMOserver.Databases[$restoreToDatabaseName]  returns null, even when the restoreToDatabaseName is not null

Comment: To get a more detailed error information I use this function: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/07/resolve-error.aspx. This will clarify which error sql server is throwing.

Comment: @Ange1 This null value is okay, because if there's no database with the requested name, the null result is what's expected. This, however, means that restore via `ImportBacpac` failed. For this is likely an issue on SQL server side, check SQL server logs for any errors.

Comment: @wallybh I will try it and give you the result thanks :)

Comment: @Vesper I agree for the fact that the null value is okay, for a new Db, but even if there is a database with that name (and here the killDatabase function should be triggered), i still have the null value. However, i will check the SQL logs to see if there is anything wrong with the connection or something

Comment: So, at the end, it was all an issue of one table, that on creation did not had a primary key... So the Error was "Tables without a clustered index are not allowed on this verion of Sql Server"... Azure and it's rigiditty...pfffffffff!!!